# R's cbind functionality in Spark Scala

Tags: r, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, cbind

I have a requirement to cbind [as it happens in R] two dataframes in spark using scala, which do not have a ID column.
Any pointers on any readily available function for it, or some other workaround for it?

Example:

DF1:

```
    Name Age
    ABC  10
    BCD  11
```

DF2:

```
    Marks
    75
    85
```

Result needed:

```
    DF3:
    Name Age Marks
    ABC  10  75
    BCD  11  85
```

Comment: To bind columns, you don't need any prior knowledge of column names. The only thing that needs to match is number of rows. You may be looking for `merge` or SQL equivalents "joins".

Comment: Yes, but i dont have any key columns to Join. I am actually looking for Spark's equivalent of R's cbind().

Comment: Have you seen this? https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8180/how-to-merge-two-data-frames-column-wise-in-apache.html

Comment: This is a workaround. I was hoping something as basic as this might already be implemented with a core function in spark!

Comment: Comments aren't really appropriate for pasting much code. Either edit your question or if you found a solution, post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works perfectly as a workaround:

```
    df1 = df1.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    df2 = df2.withColumn("id", monotonically_increasing_id())
    df3 = df2.join(df1, "id", "outer").drop("id")
```

For spark 1.6.*, the last line needs to be:

```
    df3 = df2.join(df1, df1("id") === df2("id"), "outer").drop("id")
```

Comment: since monotonically_increasing_id() doesn't guarantee consecutive sequence, doubling your `cbind` could make a trouble.

Comment: The correct form of the third line (for Spark 1.4) is: df3 = df2.join(df1, Seq("id"), "outer").drop("id")

Comment: @Curycu Yes, it is not consecutive, when multiple partitions are involved. In such a case, the upper 31 bits of the 64-bit generated ids contain the partition id, and the lower 33 bits contain the record numbers. That is why it works, even when the data is distributed across clusters.

Answer (score 0):

try this function

```
val cbind: (DataFrame, DataFrame) => DataFrame =
  (df, df2) => {
    val x =
      spark
        .createDataFrame(
          df.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map(tu => Row(tu._1.toSeq.:+(tu._2): _*)),
          df.schema.add(StructField("primaryKeyForCbind", LongType, false)))
        .withColumn("orderKeyForCbind", $"primaryKeyForCbind")
        .as("df")
    val y =
      spark
        .createDataFrame(
          df2.rdd.zipWithUniqueId.map(tu => Row(tu._1.toSeq.:+(tu._2): _*)),
          df2.schema.add(StructField("primaryKeyForCbind", LongType, false)))
        .as("df2")
    x.join(y, col("df.primaryKeyForCbind") === col("df2.primaryKeyForCbind"))
      .sort("orderKeyForCbind")
      .drop("primaryKeyForCbind", "orderKeyForCbind")
  }

val df =
  Seq(
    ("curycu", "2018-01-01"),
    ("curycu", "2018-01-07"),
    ("curycu", "2018-01-12"),
    ("curycu", "2018-01-15"),
    ("tester", "2018-01-01"),
    ("tester", "2018-01-11"),
    ("tester", "2018-01-18"))
    .toDF("id", "date")

val df2 = Seq(0, 6, 5, 3, 0, 10, 7).toDF("daygap")

val res = cbind(cbind(cbind(df, df2), df2), df)
res.printSchema
res.show

root
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)
 |-- daygap: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- daygap: integer (nullable = false)
 |-- id: string (nullable = true)
 |-- date: string (nullable = true)

+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+
|    id|      date|daygap|daygap|    id|      date|
+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+
|curycu|2018-01-01|     0|     0|curycu|2018-01-01|
|curycu|2018-01-07|     6|     6|curycu|2018-01-07|
|curycu|2018-01-12|     5|     5|curycu|2018-01-12|
|curycu|2018-01-15|     3|     3|curycu|2018-01-15|
|tester|2018-01-01|     0|     0|tester|2018-01-01|
|tester|2018-01-11|    10|    10|tester|2018-01-11|
|tester|2018-01-18|     7|     7|tester|2018-01-18|
+------+----------+------+------+------+----------+
```